# How to edit model objects in an inline formset in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, backend, formset

In Django I am trying to use an inline formset factory so a user can edit instances of a model related to a parent model via a foreignkey. For some reason the methods I am trying don't save the changes I make when I click submit.

My view is like this (not including render):

```
def edit_sets(request, exercisegroup_id):


    exercisename = ExerciseName.objects.get(pk=exercisegroup_id)
    SetLoggerFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ExerciseName, SetLogger, fields=('weight','reps',))

    formset = SetLoggerFormSet(instance=exercisename)


    if request.method == 'POST':  
      formset = SetLoggerFormSet(request.POST, instance=exercisename)
      if formset.is_valid():
         formset.save()
      else:
        formset = SetLoggerFormSet(instance=exercisename)
```

and I am displaying each form in the formset in my template so the user can individually edit the instance:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
               {{ formset.management_form}}
               <table>
                  {% for form in formset %}
                        {{ form }}
                  {% endfor %}
               </table>
               <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save set</button>
          </form>
```

Stuck as to why this isn't working. The form displays as it should and this method has previously worked for adding objects, but I am still unable to use it to replace one of those objects in the queryset. Am I missing something I should be doing differently?

Edit:

Turns out the solution was to change my request.method statement to :

```
if request.method == 'POST':  
      formset = SetsFormSet(request.POST, instance=exercisename)
      for form in formset:
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
```

Which allows me to save each form in the formset individually, seeing as I am altering only a section of the formset.

Comment: Hey, Can you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61285171/initialize-a-formset  I am trying to edit a formset but failed to render the edit form

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working for me. Maybe you have changed your environment setup or something else. When you submit your form, Is there any error showing to you? If so show us your error details.

You can try like this:

```
def edit_sets(request, exercisegroup_id):
    exercisename = ExerciseName.objects.get(pk=exercisegroup_id)
    SetLoggerFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ExerciseName, SetLogger, fields=('weight','reps',))

    formset = SetLoggerFormSet(instance=exercisename)


    if request.method == 'POST':  
      formset = SetLoggerFormSet(request.POST, instance=exercisename)
      if formset.is_valid():
         formset.save()
      else:
        print("something is wrong in validation")
        print(formset.errors)
        formset = SetLoggerFormSet(instance=exercisename)
```

Comment: Yep turns out whatever I am entering in the formset is not considered valid. Seems strange considering the fields are just simple IntegerFields. Maybe its something to do with me editing individual forms in the formset rather than the entire formset itself?

Comment: No, I don't think so `formset.errors` will return all of the related form errors

Comment: Managed to figure out the solution, I was trying to save the whole formset when I should've been saving each form individually. Thank for the help